# "We" vs "One of us" vs "Someone"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, sentence-meaning

Is there a difference between

- We
- One of us
- Someone

... will be here throughout the day to provide service

Is one of them grammatically incorrect, or would they change the meaning?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"We" means the people who are normally there will be on hand to help.

"One of us" indicates that only one person who is normally there will be on hand to help. Possibly this person will do the work of several.

"Someone" means the sentence is speaking in a general manner that help by one person will be given, but not by whom.

Comment: Thank you for spending time to help. Now with your explanation and Miriam's input, I'll go with "One of us".

Answer (score 1):

For customer service professionals, vague word choices may not be helpful to the customer. When writing, put yourself in the customer's shoes. Is it more helpful to know that one person will be available, or that someone will be available, or even to name a specific individual or department representative who will be available?

In order of preference:

1. One of us
2. Someone
3. We

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable input.